# Find the index in a n*m matrix where the element is present

Tags: c

Problem:How is +3 is equal to -3.

I have use ideone.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
long long int scan()
{
    long long int n=0;
    char ch=getchar_unlocked();
    while(ch<'0'||ch>'9')
        ch=getchar_unlocked();
    while(ch>='0'&&ch<='9')
    {
        n=(n<<3)+(n<<1)+ch-'0';
        ch=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    return n;
}
long long int a[1001][1001];
int main()
{
    int flag;
    long long int i,j,n,m,q,x;
    n=scan();
    m=scan();
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=scan();
        }
    }
    q=scan();
    while(q--)
    {
        flag=0;
        x=scan();
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                if(a[i][j]==x)
                {
                    if((a[i][j]+1)==x+1)
                    {
                    flag=1;
                    printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(flag==1)
            break;
        }
        if(flag!=1)
                printf("-1 -1\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

scan() is just a method to scan long long integers.

Input:

```
5 5
-10 -5 -3 4 9
-6 -2 0 5 10
-4 -1 1 6 12
2 3 7 8 13
100 120 130 140 150
3
0
6
5
```

Output:

```
1 2
0 1
0 2
```

I just want to display the indexes(0-based index) where the element is present.

Therefore

1) 0--> 1 2 Correct!

2) 6--> 1 0 Incorrect! It is not present. Therefore expected -1 -1

3) 3--> 0 2 Incorrect! It is present at 3 1

Comment: This code isn't very pretty. What is this program supposed to do actually?

Comment: User will input n*m matrix than followed by values...q represents the queries such that user will put a value 'x' and we are suppose to find the index of 'x' in the matrix

Comment: Answer: *`3` is obviously not equal to `-3`*, so there must be something else wrong in your code. Since you are scanning your own input character by character rather than using C libraries to do that for you, there's a lot that could go wrong here. I'd recommend after reading in the array and check values, write them back out with `printf` to make sure you scanned them properly and put them into the right variables and go from there.

Comment: Yeah my scan() method had problem.Thank you for your remarks.